# Convert Int in Request Body to Long always

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, int, long-integer

I wrote my backend in Java, and the endpoint is hit with a request body. The endpoint has a JSON body that looks like this

```
{"id": 1234, "data": {...}}
```

Now, I'm getting the request data, and storing it by the id. I want to save the ids' as longs, however, the values can be anywhere from int-valid to long-valid.

I'm using the Spring framework in order to save it. The function looks like this

```
public String getData (@RequestBody JSONObject jsonRequest) {
    Long id_long = (Long) jsonRequest.get("id");
```

However, I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

This is where I'm stuck. Sometimes the id value will be valid like 1234L, or a really long number which is in long range. However, sometimes it is int range. I haven't used Java that much so I was wondering how to do the cast properly so I always get a long.

Comment: What `JSONObject` is that? Did you try using `Long.valueOf()`?

Comment: It is the org.json.simple.JSONObject, and I didn't, because the error occurs when I try to get it out of the JSONObject. I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: You can't cast `Integer` to `Long` even though you can cast `int` to `long`. The reason is that these 2 types are classes and not primitives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is to use a **java.lang.Number** object, which is the superclass of the **Long** and **Integer** classes.  It has a **longValue()** method to get the value as a long every time.

```
public String getData (@RequestBody User user) {
    Long id_long = ((Number) jsonRequest.get("id")).longValue();
```

The longer answer would be not to use a generic class like JSONObject.  Define your own class, and use spring to bind to it...

```
public class User {
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public String getData (@RequestBody User user) {
    Long id_long = user.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` has a [longValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#longValue--) method that returns the value as a `long` (primitive). You can assign it to `id_long` and let the [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) wrapping it into a `Long`.

```
public String getData (@RequestBody JSONObject jsonRequest) {
    Long id_long = jsonRequest.get("id").longValue();
}
```